# "Grid Stylesheet" GSS in production?

Tags: css

I've scoured the web and haven't found any discussions on GSS (http://gridstylesheets.org/)  aside from the developers' comments. Does anyone know of any "medium" to "large" scale projects which have used GSS, more specifically, how to implement GSS in larger projects ( yes, I didn't define "larger" but let your intuition and common sense guide you )

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be a poll, asking for a list of external resources/demonstrations.

Comment: well obviously `the Grid` is a large scale project using it. :)